# VUEJS2 - CKEDITOR does not load contentsCss

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, ckeditor

Currently working on a website using vuejs2, we integrated the ckeditor4-vue a while back.

Now the issue has been risen that the font does not match the rest of the application. They would like to default to 'Lato', sans-serif.

As shown at the bottom the implementation, it's visible that we use contentsCss in our config to load an internal CSS stylesheet. (Located at localhost:8080/ckeditor/content.css)

But this does not load, is contentsCss supported for ckeditor4-vue? Is there another solution?

Currently we load the ckeditor instance in the main.js as following;

```
...
import CKEditor from "ckeditor4-vue";
Vue.use(CKEditor);
...
const app = new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
...
```

We made a wrapper for our CKEditor component to re-use it as we do not need to define it multiple times. This component is configured like such; (small display, contains a lot more)

```
<template>
  <ckeditor
    @ready="onReady"
    :value="value"
    @input="handleInput"
    :config="{ ...localConfig, readOnly: readOnly, fullPage: true }"
  >
  </ckeditor>
</template>

export default {
  name: "RTE",
  props: {
    editorConfig: {
      required: false,
      type: Object
    },
    value: {},
    targetObject: { required: true, type: String },
    targetUuid: { type: String },
    readOnly: { required: false, type: Boolean, default: false }
  },
  computed: {
    config() {
      return {
        language: i18n._vm.locale,
        toolbar: [
          // { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
          {
            name: "basicstyles",
            items: [
              "Bold",
              "Italic",
              "Underline",
              "Strike",
              "Subscript",
              "Superscript",
              "-",
              "CopyFormatting",
              "RemoveFormat"
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "paragraph",
            items: [
              "NumberedList",
              "BulletedList",
              "-",
              "Outdent",
              "Indent",
              "-",
              "Blockquote",
              "-",
              "JustifyLeft",
              "JustifyCenter",
              "JustifyRight",
              "JustifyBlock"
            ]
          },
          { name: "links", items: ["Link", "Unlink"] },
          {
            name: "insert",
            items: ["Image", "Table", "HorizontalRule", "SpecialChar"]
          },
          "/",
          { name: "clipboard", items: ["Undo", "Redo", "-"] },
          { name: "styles", items: ["Format", "FontSize"] },
          { name: "colors", items: ["TextColor", "BGColor"] },
          { name: "tools", items: ["Maximize", "-"] },
          { name: "document", items: ["Source", "-", "Sourcedialog"] }
        ],
        extraPlugins:
          "format,font,colorbutton,justify,uploadimage,image,sourcedialog",
        uploadUrl:
          "https://a.link.com/there/needs/to/be/a/random/url/in/here",
        removePlugins: "sourcearea",
        height: 300,
        allowedContent: true,
        filebrowserUploadUrl: this.isAwareness()
          ? "https://a.link.com/there/needs/to/be/a/random/url/in/here"
          : "",
        contentsCss: ["/ckeditor/content.css"]
      };
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So `fullPage: true` in my config blocks contentsCss from being used. If you disable fullPage it will load the css.